# moving from oracle sql to couchBase db just by changing connection

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, couchbase

I have a spring mvc application that works on oracle server, I am currently using the spring JPA to store and retrieve data. can i move from oracle sql to couchbase server just by changing the data source, If so how do I configure my datasource to work with couchbase
The bean definition is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="org.test.project"></context:component-scan>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" ></context:property-placeholder>

<jpa:repositories base-package="org.test.project"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryBean"></jpa:repositories>

<bean id="dbClassImpl" class="org.test.project.DbClassImpl" />


<!--EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.test.project" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="someurl" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Comment: ref [Spring Data Couchbase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official documentation about it https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#configuration-xml

However, you will need to change a few extra things to make it work:

1 - One of the main advantages of Document Databases is to avoid unnecessary joins. If you simply transition from relational to Document without changing your model, you won't get the most of it. (https://blog.couchbase.com/json-data-modeling-rdbms-users/)

2 - Couchbase don't support LocaDateTime/ZonnedDateTime yet, you will need to write a converter.

3 - Your repositories should have a few extra annotations 
(https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/)

4 - If you are using JPQL, you will need to slightly modify it to use the N1QL syntax (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.n1ql)